# Javascript inheritance extending more than 2 times

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to make some examples with Javascript inheritance, and I'm kinda surprised to get a **maximum call stack size exceeded**.

I'm extending a base class more than 1 time, and then an error is thrown.
It should be possible to extend a base class just more than 1 time, right?

```
--> Class A
 --> Class B extends A
  --> Class C extends B
```

You can view it in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gPYDd/3/ or browse code below.

```
function View () {
   this.__id = null;    
}

View.prototype.init = function (id) {
   this.__id = id; 
}

View.prototype.render = function() {
   this.__element = document.getElementById(this.__id);
   this.__originalContent = this.__element.innerHTML;
   this.__element.innerHTML = 'Do some basic stuff';
}

View.prototype.destroy = function () {
    this.__element.innerHTML = this.__originalContent;   
}

function ExtendedView () {  
    View.call(this);
}

ExtendedView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
ExtendedView.prototype.constructor = ExtendedView;
ExtendedView.prototype.parent = View.prototype;

ExtendedView.prototype.render = function () {
    this.parent.render.call(this);
    this.__originalColor = this.__element.style.color;
    this.__element.style.color = 'red';   
}

ExtendedView.prototype.destroy = function () {
    this.parent.destroy.call(this);
    this.__element.style.color = this.__originalColor;   
}


function SuperExtendedView () {  
    ExtendedView.call(this);
}

SuperExtendedView.prototype = Object.create(ExtendedView.prototype);
SuperExtendedView.prototype.constructor = SuperExtendedView;
SuperExtendedView.prototype.parent = ExtendedView.prototype;

SuperExtendedView.prototype.render = function () {
    this.parent.render.call(this);
    this.__originalFontSize = this.__element.style.fontSize;
    this.__element.style.fontSize = '3em';   
}

SuperExtendedView.prototype.destroy = function () {
    this.parent.destroy.call(this);
    this.__element.style.fontSize = this.__originalFontSize;   
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible in this setup I guess :P

Comment: If somebody have an idea, that would be awesome, I love this pattern.